# Mouse hover on Sprite object Pyglet?

Tags: python, events, sprite, mouse, pyglet

I want to know if there is a way to catching mouse hover on sprite object with Pyglet?

```
my_sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(image, x, y)
```

something like this in Tkinter :

```
sprite.bind(circle, "<Enter>", on_enter)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a demo code for detecting mouse hover on a moving gif sprite,  u can have a try and change it to what u like.

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.window import mouse


animation = pyglet.image.load_animation('ur_image_gif_path_like_xxx.gif')
bin = pyglet.image.atlas.TextureBin()
animation.add_to_texture_bin(bin)
sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(img=animation)
window = pyglet.window.Window()

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    sprite.draw()

def update(dt):
    sprite.x += dt*10

@window.event
def on_mouse_motion(x, y, dx, dy):
    # print(x, y, dx, dy)
    image_width = sprite.image.get_max_width()
    image_height = sprite.image.get_max_height()
    if sprite.x+image_width>x>sprite.x and sprite.y+image_height>y>sprite.y:
        print("mouse hover sprite")
    else:
        print("mouse leave sprite")

pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update, 1/60.)
pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer :D, but the problems is when you have multiple `sprite object` (for ex 50 sprite on screen)  and calculating like that for all sprite is such a tedious task. Is there any better way to do this ? thanks again

Comment: sorry, but I do have no other ideas if there are many sprites(say 1000 or more) to be calculated, besides, `image_width ` and `image_height` can be move out from function`on_mouse_motion` as global variables to reduce calculation pressure.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a boundary-checking handler. See [this discussion in pyglet-users](https://groups.google.com/g/pyglet-users/c/VgLlDPH6cuI?pli=1). The bottom line is that pyglet does not have built-in handlers for sprite bounds checking. Although the code was not very clear or well documented, the above respondent showed a rudimentary object-boundary-testing loop. Not only "crude but effective," it is also typically what a handler would be doing for you anyway.